# Unable to perform unmarshalling at .. Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'

Tags: hibernate

Something happened. I didnt change anything but changed wrong name from "hibernateaa.cfg.xml to hibernate.cfg.xml" and now its crashing

Error code

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 6 and column 63 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version ="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    
    <persistence-unit name="MavenHibernateProject" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/javadatabase?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
            
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" 
            value="root" />
            
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" 
            value="Password1" />
            
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            

            
        </properties>
        

        
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i had 2 hibernate.cfg.xml files, 1 in source, the other in resources. So the one in source was the good one, and the one in resources was the bad one. I just copied from src to resources. and its all fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Password1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/javadatabase?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```